# Removal of Pokemon stop

Tags: pokemon-go

Pokemon stop is at a gated community. Dangerous entrance/exit with golf carts, cars and maintenance equipment.

How can this stop be removed?

Answer (score 10):

There is a form you can fill out to make such a request:

https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=341148